# How to pass these parameters into an NSString nsuserdefault

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop, int, nsuserdefaults

I have 14 nsuserdefualt save keys and instead of adding all 14 of them I created a for loop to handle this. However I am getting an error that says too many arguments. I am probably having a brain fart and forgot something. Any tips or suggestions will be appreciated.

Edit: I am trying to read the saved data.

```
   for (int n=0; n==14; n++ ) {
    NSString *emailBody=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Enhancers: %@",

                         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                          stringForKey:@"Enhancer%i",n]];
      }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had an extra argument in your format string specifically "n" that should have been placed in a different format for stringForKey:. Something like this should clear things up:

```
for (int n=0; n==14; n++ ) {
    NSString *stringFromDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",n]];
    NSString *emailBody=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Enhancers: %@",stringFromDefaults];
}
```